# Is the set of eventually recurrent continued fraction expansions closed under multiplication by positive integers?

Tags: continued-fractions, diophantine-approximation

I'd like to know if the set of eventually recurrent continued fraction expansions is closed under multiplication by positive integers. Is any result known about this? If so, are there any resources or simple proofs that show this?

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! Please provide some more details and background for your question, so others will find it easier to give the kind of answer that you are looking for.

Comment: If you mean a [periodic regular continued fraction](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PeriodicContinuedFraction.html) then it's a root of a quadratic with integer coefficients, and the answer is "yes."  If this isn't what you mean, please explain.

Comment: I mean recurrent here in the sense that every sub-sequence that appears once in the continued fraction expansion appears infinitely often e.g. the Thue-Morse word. By eventually I mean that there may be some finite prefix which does not repeat infinitely often, but after this prefix the sequence is recurrent i.e. $[b_0,b_1,...,b_n,$ **w** $]$ where **w** is recurrent.

Comment: Then I think the link I posted answer your question.

Comment: Not quite, it's possible to be recurrent but not periodic e.g. the [Thue-Morse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence) word on any two positive integers a and b would be recurrent but not periodic. Replace 0 with a and 1 with b in the standard form shown in the link. Periodic continued fractions are a subset of recurrent continued fractions.